# format jbuilder with code, message and data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httpresponse, jbuilder

i have the following jbuilder class:

```
json.array!(@users) do |user|
  json.user_id user.id
  json.user_name user.full_name
  ...
end
```

But i want all @users data inside a :data attribute. And a code and a message for the response. 
Exactly like this:

```
{ :code => 200, :message => "Succesful request", :data => {[{user_id: 12, user_name: "Jason"},{user_id: 13, user_name: "Peter"}...]} }
```

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should't use `array!` method.
Maybe you can do them as below:

```
json.code    response.status
json.message 'you want to return message here'
json.data @users do |user|
  json.user_id user.id
  json.user_name user.full_name
  ...
end
```

Comment: thanks shoji! This also works:
json.data do
  json.array! @users do |user|
    json.user_id user.id
    json.user_name user.full_name
    ...
  end
end